# Exclude property when selecting data

Tags: entity-framework

I have a class with a virtual property (`public virtual List<Ingredients>`), but in some cases I don't want to get that data. How can I do this? I know about `.Include` and `.Select`, but if I do that, I need to change lots of code cause in my repository I return a Queryable and Service layer too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An indirect answer: I would not expose `IQueryable` in a service layer. For (at least) three reasons:

- You must keep the context alive for when a navigation property is accessed.
- The layers that use your service layer can profoundly influence the SQL emitted to the database. You want to be in control of that that in your service or repository.
- Unit testing your service layer is very hard.

So if you expose *`IEnumerable`s* of objects that you need in your application you can offer objects that have exactly those navigation properties loaded that are needed in a specific scenario. E.g. a maintenance function for product entities (name etc.) would get bare products only (and no code would ever access ingredients). A function that composes products from ingredients would get its ingredients as well. Service/repository methods should have parameters to specify what you need.

If you want 100% guarantee that lazy navigation properties are not going to be accessed you need to expose projected objects (or DTO's) to your application.

Comment: Thank for your answer. If I do not return a IQueryable<T>, should I create a method that do a expecific code, like one that returns data ordered by Id, another that returns data ordered by Name?

Comment: You can always do ordering in memory. Paging is a different story. it is not uncommon to have methods that specify the number of rows to be returned and the offset and, indeed, an ordering. It is quite a hassle to implement this, but it is rewarding in terms of separation of layers and testability.

Answer (score 0):

By default related properties are not returned and you need to use an Include() to specify returning a related property.
This may not always be clear as if you are using lazy loading you do not need to explicitly request  the related property, EF will determine if the related property is required when it is requested and add it to the database request.

To test this force the LINQ query to execute when you declare it by appending .First() and the look at the object returned which should have no related properties.

**Edit**
It is not possible to load only certain properties from a related property. If you load the related property all its properties will automatically be loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, but like I said I want to exclude in some cases for performance improvements. I need something like DB.Products.Exclude('Ingredients').

Comment: In what circumstance do you need to exclude them? If you dont add them using an Include() they will be excluded already...

Comment: Yes, it will, but it is now virtual cause I need it in all my codes, except for a new situation that I don't need it, so I wanna exclude it.

Comment: Hmmm I cant visualize that scenario since you seem to be using the DbContext for each circumstance. Maybe post the code of both scenarios so we can look at them and give more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

You cann simply build a class SubClass (that inherit from SomeCompany) and includes the Property you need, that schould not be included into your proxy class (SomeCompany).

For example a class

### SomeCompany

```
public class SomeCompany
{
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual Company MyCompany { get; set; }
}

public class SomeCompanyEx : SomeCompany
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public override Company MyCompany
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myCompany;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this.myCompany, value);

            if (value != null)
            {
                this.CompanyName = value.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                this.CompanyName = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class SomeCompanyEx you can use, for example, in list object and so on... So you have now the property CompanyName you can use in your program, but no in your proxy classes.

Comment: SetProperty is only available with Prism.

Comment: @codeMonkey: that's not true. You can implement your own class with corresponding code